std::unordered_set with memory location control?
I would like to have a data structure that stores items of some type 'Key' but additionally provides an access to the memory location where it is stored. More specifically, consider the following types:
struct ItemPtr;

struct Item
{
  Key key;
  ItemPtr* ptr; 
};

struct ItemPtr
{
  Item* item;
};


Item's should be stored in something like std::unordered_set; I need to be able to add item, remove item, and find the item by 'key'. ItemPtr's will be stored in a separate data structure; I will write my own code that will move ItemPtr's around. There should be one-to-one correspondence between Item's and ItemPtr's (with corresponding pointers pointing to each other). Therefore, whenever std::unordered_set moves Item i to a different location, it should update i->ptr->item accordingly.
Is it possible to achieve this with std, or do I need to reimplement std::unordered_set ?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

std::unordered_... containers don't move the elements in memory, that's why they're slower than many third-party hashmap implementations.

Sounds like you are asking for transparent comparators. These exist for std::unordered_set since C++20

Why would you need to move that memory around, using a pointer to a pointer? It will only end in double book keeping.  What is the actual issue you're trying to solve with this? It really feels like you're adding accidental complexity where none might be needed.
